# how to detect battery failure

Tags: batteries

I want to design a LIPO battery control circuit for 10 batteries 3V7 500mAh connected in 2P5S.
This circuit need to control the charger and disconct the charger in case of battery overvoltage or overcurrent before the batteries will be damaged. 
Is there a circuit to detect a battery failures : overvoltage, overcurrent and overheating ?

Comment: Seiko makes a large line of lithium ion protection IC's. I believe they are the market leader in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: yes. The are a number of lithium ion PCB that are created based on the number of cells in series. They will stop charge or discharge if any cell is over voltage, under voltage over current, or short circuit. Some of them can be customized for size of current etc.  search google or ebay for lithium ion PCB and you will find what you are looking for.